# Hide, Show and Replacing PDF form content blocks with multiple fillable fields

Tags: pdf, conditional-formatting, forms, adobe-indesign, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a single fillable PDF form that provides hiding/showing/replacing of context-specific signature blocks containing multiple fields, after selecting a radio button.

Ideally, when a specific radio button is selected by the user, the signature block group pertaining to the button selection, will appear in a specific position in the PDF document and no others will be visible.

So, this will require not only Show/Hide, but also reposition and replace. The resulting fillable PDF will be used buth electronically and printed.

I have built the document in Adobe InDesign and am providing an image seen below. The example image shows the three signature blocks stacked at the bottom. The topmost block would be the default view and position. The remaining two would become visible (one at a time) in the space previously occupied by the default block.

[Example Document Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClypJ.png)

Can anyone provide a solution here? It will be greatly appreciated.